# Definition of "proband" in CNV analysis

Tags: cnv

I am reading [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/mp2011154) regarding *de novo* CNV analysis in Schizophrenia:

> Accordingly, such CNVs must frequently occur as recurrent de novo mutations. In a sample of 662 schizophrenia **proband–parent** trios, we found that rare de novo CNV mutations were significantly more frequent in cases (5.1% all cases, 5.5% family history negative) compared with 2.2% among 2623 controls, confirming the involvement of de novo CNVs in the pathogenesis of schizophrenia.

I assumed that **proband** stands for the sample being tested (child of the parents), however, I couldn't find an explicit definition for it. Is it just the sample being tested, or does it imply additional details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*answer from @maximilian-press, converted from comments:*

- https://www.genome.gov/genetics-glossary/Proband
- https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proband

> A **proband** is an individual affected with a disorder who is the first subject in a study (as of a genetic character in a family lineage) who brings a genetic disorder to the attention of the medical community.